# Updating a 2 dimensional list in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, slice

I have a large two dimensional list of integer values.  I need to update a slice of this list.

Currently I am using the syntax :

```
pixelArray[20:24][150:154] = [255 for i in range(4)]
```

The column indexes do exist in the table.  And I tried just setting the slice directly to the value 255 but python told me I need to use an iterator to set multiple values.  Is there an easier way to accomplish this?

Comment: You seem to be trying to set a single position - why use slicing? You may want to consider a `numpy` array.

Comment: The right side is the same as `[255] * 4`.

Comment: I need to update a subset of the values in my list to 255.  What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Use a `numpy` array instead of a list of lists, then you can do e.g. `pixelArray[20:24,150:154] = 255`.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with

```
pixelArray[20][150:154] = [255] * 4
pixelArray[21][150:154] = [255] * 4
pixelArray[22][150:154] = [255] * 4
pixelArray[23][150:154] = [255] * 4
```

or

```
for i in range(20, 24):
    pixelArray[i][150:154] = [255] * 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it sufficient to do something like:

```
for a in pixelArray[20:24]:
    for b in range(150,155):
        a[b] = 255
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this one:

```
pixelArray[20:24,150:154]= [255]
```

Comment: just noticed @jonrsharpe answered this much earlier.